# Run trigger after transaction, not on each row - PostgreSQL 9.4

Tags: postgresql

I have this trigger to ensure that the total sum of all votes does not pass 100:

```
CREATE FUNCTION limit_votes() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $limit_votes$
    DECLARE
        votes_total int;
    BEGIN
        votes_total := NEW.vote + (SELECT SUM(vote) FROM cars WHERE portfolio_id = NEW.portfolio_id AND car != NEW.car);
        IF votes_total > 100 THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'votes_limit_exceeded';
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$limit_votes$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER limit_votes BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON cars FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE limit_votes();
```

It should be mentioned that a "vote" can be updated, so it's not only INSERTs.
This is where my problem occur, as one user could change the votes between cars and then the trigger gets issued as an update on a single row could exceed the limit off 100, before the other updates decrease the other votes.

I hope it make sense.

I would like the trigger to be called AFTER a BEGIN ... COMMIT, so I can updates multiple rows before checking everything is in order - but also raise an exception and not save the result if a user tries to update the votes to more than 100.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The trigger has to be a constraint and "after" trigger. Then you can use DEFERRABLE:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER limit_votes
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON cars
DEFERRABLE
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE limit_votes();
```

See the docs:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: Changing to "CREATE TRIGGER limit_votes BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON cars DEFERRABLE FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE limit_votes();" fails with syntax error at or near "DEFERRABLE".

Comment: When it's a AFTER trigger, what happens if something "illegal" gets updated? Will it be discarded still?

Comment: @MichaelNielsen Yes, I think it will rollback entire transaction. But check it to be 100% sure.

Comment: This only worked for me by adding INITIALLY DEFERRED:

 `CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER limit_votes
 AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON cars
 DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED 
 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE limit_votes();`

Comment: It needs the `INITIALLY DEFERRED`.

From the documentation:
`INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
INITIALLY DEFERRED
If a constraint is deferrable, this clause specifies the default time to check the constraint. If the constraint is INITIALLY IMMEDIATE, it is checked after each statement. This is the default. If the constraint is INITIALLY DEFERRED, it is checked only at the end of the transaction. The constraint check time can be altered with the SET CONSTRAINTS command.`

Answer (score 7):

According to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createtrigger.html

Since this should be a deferrable constraint and you want to trigger the procedure execution after the transaction you need the following,

## INITIALLY DEFERRED

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER limit_votes
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON cars
DEFERRABLE
INITIALLY DEFERRED 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE limit_votes();
```

## INITIALLY IMMEDIATE

If we have wanted to trigger the procedure execution after each statement.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER limit_votes
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON cars
DEFERRABLE
INITIALLY IMMEDIATE 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE limit_votes();
```

Answer (score 4):

While the existing answers take care of the `run trigger after transaction` part, the function is still going to run for each row. To ensure it only runs once you can add an intermediary trigger on an extra `triggers` table as follows:

```
-- triggers table for logging and firing a trigger only once
drop table if exists triggers;
create table triggers(
    "tx_id" bigint primary key,
    "name" text,
    "exec_count" int default 0
);

-- the original trigger now fires an insert into the triggers table
create constraint trigger cars_insert_update
after insert or update on cars
deferrable
initially deferred
for each row 
execute function insert_trigger();

-- trigger function to insert a row in the triggers table
create or replace function insert_trigger()
returns trigger as $insert_trigger$
begin
    insert into triggers
    values (txid_current(), tg_name, 0)
    on conflict (tx_id)
    do nothing;
    
    return null;
end
$insert_trigger$ language plpgsql;

-- trigger to run the original trigger function
-- it will only fire once since updates are ignored
drop trigger if exists triggers_insert on triggers;
create constraint trigger triggers_insert
after insert on triggers
deferrable
initially deferred
for each row
when (new."name" = 'cars_insert_update')
execute function limit_votes();
```

Comment: If you want to run the trigger per statement, you could simply use `for each statement` instead of `for each row`

Comment: Not if it's a constraint (deferred) trigger.