# Is there an equivalent to Oracles CQN in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-migration

we have to convert an Ooracle database to PostgreSQL. Our database is using triggers and `CQN` (Continous Query Notification).

Triggers should be save. But we need a functionality in PostgreSQL which mimics CQN.

We use CQN to call a PL/SQL procedure after a `commit` of a table. In CQN you can define a query, which will be called after a `commit`. When this query returns a result, then the PL/SQL procedure will be called.

Is there a way to call a procedure in PostgreSQL, when the content of a defined table changed in a transaction?

Comment: Would a Job apply in such concept?

Comment: I don't know. I'm new on postgresql and googled a bit about jobs.I found an extension, to schedule jobs cronlike. But this is not exactly what i'm looking for. I don't want to do polling and we want to use an RDS database from Amazon. I'm not sure, if it's possible to instal extensions there.
We want to have a mechanism to start a procedure/function after a commit with changed data in a specific table. If this is possible with a job and without an extension i would be grateful, if you could give me an example or hint.

Comment: Well, maybe you are after a a trigger after commit. Take a look at this thread, I think it is already what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277313/run-trigger-after-transaction-not-on-each-row-postgresql-9-4

Comment: The closest thing is would be to use LISTEN/NOTIFY and send the notifications in a triggers

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thx, this looks promising. I'll have a look into this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As far as i see, is the notification api for client applications written in languages like c and needs polling, if there are notifications in the queue. So i can't define a psql function which 'listens' to a commit event.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this feature from postgres would look like CQN, although it's definitely not calling SPs(and the transactional MVCC model of postgres means it'd be potentially dangerous to do so)
[postgresql listen](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-listen.html)

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: What is "this feature"?

Comment: see my comment to a_horse_with_no_name